# What happens to strenth of bar magnet when it falls through the coil

Tags: electromagnetism

When bar magnet falls through the coil , acceleration of it beames less than g  because of current in coil ,but what happens to bar magnet there is some flux change happening in bar magnet also . As a result of this pole strength should become more ? Can somebody explain ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the interaction of a bar magnet with the induced magnetic field of a coil, on the pole strength of the bar magnet, is not fundamentally different than the effect of any other external magnetic field of similar strength and rate of change, which could be produced, for instance, by another permanent magnet or an electromagnet.

In general, pole strength is a property of a magnet and just the fact that a magnet is exposed to an external magnetic field and the two fields superimpose with each other, does not automatically mean that this property should change.

Of course, if the external field is relatively strong, the pole strength of a magnet could change, temporarily or permanently, depending on how soft or hard the magnetic material is, but it would be due to structural changes inside the magnet - not due to the change of flux during the exposure.

Answer (score -1):

> there is some flux change happening in bar magnet also

Oh yes! The entire field arrangement of the system as a whole is quite complex.

The more important part, however, is that currents will be induced in the bar magnet. You'll notice this when you grab the magnet again - it will be warmer (maybe too little to notice however).

In fact, you don't need the bar magnet at all. Any reasonably conductive material will have the same effect. You can try this yourself if you have any flat copper sheet (you can get it at most hardware stores) and move it between the poles of a strong magnet.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer , can we say pole strength of bar magnet will increase ?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on the geometry. The rule the system follows is Lens' Law, so the field created by the current will always be the opposite of the external magnet's. So if you drop the bar magnet in one way its "natural field" is being added to, but if you drop it another way, maybe not.

Comment: I should also note that there are many materials that will retain a changed field after this "trip". Soft iron is a good example; take a bit of metal coat hanger and do this experiment and you'll find it comes out the end with some of the field "baked in". Now tap it on the floor a couple of times and it's gone again.